# how to add the value of a (list text) field as a class

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a CT on which I have a field called `monetary-type` which is of type `List (text)` and its "Allowed values list" is:

```
EUR|Euros
USD|Dollars
GBP|Pounds
```

When this field is rendered from a view (FORMAT: Show: Fields) it's being rendered as:

```
<span class="views-field views-field-field-monetary-type">
  <span class="field-content">Dollars</span>
</span>
```

When rendered from a node view it shows as:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-monetary-type field-type-list-text field-label-above field-wrapper">
  Dollars
</div>
```

For both those 2 cases I'd like to also have a class with the selected value, in this case `value-USD`, appended into the classnames of the wrapper.

What is the easiest (non intrusive) way I can achieve this? Ideally without having to touch existing views or node displays.

I use https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

For view field, please implements `template_preprocess_views_view_fields()`

Reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/1407442#comment-6509858

**Code Example**

```php
// assume the field name is 'field_text' and
// view name is 'text and view display id is 'page'
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'test' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
    foreach ($variables['fields'] as $id => $object) {
      if ($id == 'field_text') {
        $field_output = $view->style_plugin->get_field($view->row_index, $id);

        if (!empty($field_output)) {
          if ($object->element_type) {
            $class = '';
            if ($object->handler->options['element_default_classes']) {
              $class = 'field-content';
            }

            if ($classes = $object->handler->element_classes($view->row_index)) {
              if ($class) {
                $class .= ' ';
              }
              $class .=  $classes;
            }

            $class .=  ' ' . drupal_html_class("value-$field_output");

            $pre = '<' . $object->element_type;
            if ($class) {
              $pre .= ' class="' . $class . '"';
            }
            $field_output = $pre . '>' . $field_output . '</' . $object->element_type . '>';
          }
        }
        $variables['fields'][$id]->content = $field_output;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For node field, please implements `template_preprocess_field()`

**Code Example**

```php
// Assume the field name is 'field_text'
function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  if ($element['#field_name'] === 'field_text') {
    $value = $element['#items'][0]['value'];
    $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class("value-$value");
  }
}
```

**Note 1**: I would recommend using lower case for class name.
**Note 2**: `view_field_name` is different from `node_field_name`

Comment: Indeed, I didn't test the code. Let me try first. Get you back soon.

Comment: @cherouvim I've fixed above code. Both snippet should work now. Implementing `template_preprocess_views_view_fields()` seems quite dirty. I am thinking if there is any better way.

Comment: @cherouvim I can't think of other simpler way... LOL

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['field']->field == 'field_monetary_type') {
    $value = $vars['row']->field_field_monetary_type[0]['raw']['value'];
    $vars['output'] = '<span class="value-' . $value . '">' . check_plain($vars['output']) . '</span>';
  }
}

function mytheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
   if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_monetary_type') {
     $value = $variables['element']['#items'][0]['value'];
     $variables['classes_array'][] = "value-$value";
  }
}
```

Note that for the view field I'm wrapping the output into a span containing the class I need.